# Haskell: lift vs liftIO

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

In what situations should `liftIO` be used? When I'm using `ErrorT String IO`, the `lift` function works to lift IO actions into `ErrorT`, so `liftIO` seems superfluous.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

`lift` always lifts from the "previous" layer. If you need to lift from the second layer, you would need `lift . lift` and so on.

On the other hand, `liftIO` always lifts from the IO layer (which, when present, is always on the bottom of the stack). So, if you have more than 2 layers of monads, you will appreciate `liftIO`.

Compare the type of the argument in the following lambdas:

```
type T = ReaderT Int (WriterT String IO) Bool

> :t \x -> (lift x :: T)
\x -> (lift x :: T) :: WriterT String IO Bool -> T

> :t \x -> (liftIO x :: T)
\x -> (liftIO x :: T) :: IO Bool -> T
```

Comment: I generally will use `liftIO` to lift to the IO layer even if `lift` is sufficient, because then I can change the monad stack and the code still works.

Comment: @John: good point. And also it makes it obvious that you're lifting IO and not any other monad.

Comment: I'm a newbie: `lift` in this answer (and the question) is assumed to be from `Control.Monad.Trans.Class`, I guess?  Not the  `Monadic lifting` or the general lifting as described in the first section [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Lifting#Lifting_in_general)?

Answer (score 40):

liftIO is just a shortcut to the IO Monad, whichever the Monad you are in. Basically, liftIO equals to using a variable number of lifts. At first this might sound redundant but using liftIO has one big advantage: it makes your IO code indpendent of the actual Monad construction so you can reuse the same code no matter the number of layer your final Monad has been built of (this is quite important when writing a monad transformer).

On the ohter hand, liftIO is not coming for free, as lift does: the Monad transformers you're using must have support for it, e.g. the Monad you're in must be an instance of the MonadIO class, but most Monads nowadays do (and of course, the type-checker will check this for you at compile time: that's the strength of Haskell!).

Answer (score 8):

Previous answers all explain the difference quite well. I just wanted to shed a some light on the inner workings so that it could be easier to understand how `liftIO` isn't something magical (for the novice Haskellers like me).

```
liftIO :: IO a -> m a
```

is a wise tool just build upon

```
lift :: (Control.Monad.Trans.Class.MonadTrans t, Monad m) => m a -> t m a
```

and *most often* used when the bottom monad is `IO`. For the `IO` monad it's definition is quite simple.

```
class (Monad m) => MonadIO m where
  liftIO :: IO a -> m a

instance MonadIO IO where
  liftIO = id
```

That simple... `liftIO` is in fact just `id` for the `IO` monad and basically `IO` is the only one that comes within the definition of the type class.

The thing is, when we have a monad type which is composed of several layers of monad transformers over `IO`, we better have an `MonadIO` instance for each one of those monad transformer layers. For example the `MonadIO` instance of `MaybeT m` requires `m` to be of `MonadIO` typeclass as well.

Writing a `MonadIO` instance is basically a very simple task too. For `MaybeT m` it is defined like

```
instance (MonadIO m) => MonadIO (MaybeT m) where
  liftIO = lift . liftIO
```

or for `StateT s m`

```
instance (MonadIO m) => MonadIO (StateT s m) where
  liftIO = lift . liftIO
```

they are all the same. Imagine when you have a 4 layer transformer stack then you either need to do `lift . lift . lift . lift $ myIOAction` or just `liftIO myIOAction`. If you think about it, every `lift . liftIO` will take you one layer down in the stack up until it digs all the way down to `IO` at where `liftIO` is defined as `id` and finalizes with the same code like composed `lift`s above.

So this is basically why regardless of the transformer stack configuration, provided that all underlaying layers are members of `MonadIO` and `MonadTrans` a single `liftIO` is just fine.

Comment: This is a great answer that finally helped me to get it: if each monad in the stack is an instance of MonadIO and if IO is included at the bottom of the stack, then the succession of lift . liftIO calls works its way down the stack, each lift .liftIO calling the liftIO of the monad one level down, in a chain, until liftIO for IO is reached, which equals id, itself.