# Different type of function and `in do statement`

Tags: haskell

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  case args of
    [] -> putStrLn "Give an argument!"
```

It works, but why? Returned type is `IO ()`. `getArgs` returned `IO [String]` ( not `IO ()`). So it should raise an error.

---

```
type C = ErrorT String IO
main :: C ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    case args of
      [] -> putStrLn "Give an argument!"
```

`putStrLn` tries to return `IO ()`. But it isn't compatible with `C`. So, should I `liftIO`? I see that I should. Could you show me how does `liftIO` works here? Why I have to use `liftIO` with `getArgs`?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more why you think there'd be a problem?  Why would `arg`'s type matter? Do you think `args` is the return value of `main`?

Comment: Why do you think it should raise an error? If the type of  `getArgs` is `IO [String]`, then the type of `args` in `do { args <- getArgs; ... }` is `[String]`. Then `case args of { .. }` must have type `IO ()` because it is the final statement in the do block, which has type `IO ()` (due to the annotation). Then each pattern in the case must bind something of type `[String]` and produce an `IO ()`. Clearly `[]` is a pattern of type `[String]` and `putStrLn .. :: IO ()`. This is exactly what the typechecker does.

Comment: The type of a `do` block is the type of the _last_ statement -- in this case, of `case ...` which has the same type of `putStrLn ".."` which is `IO ()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To figure out what is going on, you can try de-sugaring you function:

```
main :: IO ()
main = getArgs >>= \ args ->
    case args of
        [] -> putStrLn "Give an argument!"
```

Here, `getArgs` has type `IO [String]` and the function (let's call it `f`) has type `[String] -> IO ()`. Now lets see what's going on with `(>>=)`:

```
(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b

-- a unifies with [String] and m with IO
(getArgs >>=) :: ([String] -> IO b) -> IO b
(>>=) :: IO [String] -> ([String] -> IO b) -> IO b

-- b unifies with ()
getArgs >>= f :: IO ()
(>>=) :: IO [String] -> ([String] -> IO ()) -> IO ()
```

For your example with `C`, there are three things wrong:

- GHC expects `main` to have type `IO ()`, but it has type `C ()` in your snippet
- `getArgs` is expected to have type `C [String]`, but it has type `IO [String]`
- same for `putStrLn`, which must have type `C ()`

To fix this, since `ErrorT` is a monad transformer, you can `lift` a monadic action to the level of the transformer with `lift`.

`liftIO` is a `lift` operation that can be applied only with monad transforming `IO`. The interesting thing is that it can work with any monad transformer (with as much monad transformer depth as you want): With `liftIO`, you can work with `T1 (T2 (... (Tn IO)...)) a` for any `n` where `Tn` are monad transformers.

You can notice their kind of similar signatures:

```
lift :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => m a -> t m a
liftIO :: MonadIO m => IO a -> m a
```

You don't need to specify IO for m, in the signature of `liftIO`, because it's instance of MonadIO already tells us that it can perform only IO actions.

To conclude, this is how you would use `liftIO` in your program:

```
type C = ErrorT String IO
main :: IO ()
main = runErrorT go >>= print  -- print the result of type `Either String ()`
    where go :: C ()
          go = do
              args <- liftIO getArgs
              case args of
                [] -> liftIO $ putStrLn "Give an argument!"
```

But, here, since you don't use any features of the `ErrorT` monad, the code is not really a good example.

Also, note that if you are talking about `ErrorT` in the `mtl` package, it is deprecated, consider using `ExceptT`.

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921237/haskell-lift-vs-liftio#3921280) for more information about `lift` vs `liftIO`

Comment: @Gilgamesz I'm sorry I can't see what you edited in your post :/

Comment: I missed to click: EDIT ;).

Comment: Ok, I found the problem in my reasoning: "`getArgs` is expected to have type `C [String]`, but it has type `IO [String]`". Why expected type is `C [String]`? After all, The type of a do block is the type of the last statement, so it should be ok.

Comment: @Gilgamesz if you are in the context of a monad, you can only run monadic action wrapped in that monad. Here, if your function has type `C ()`, you can only write things such as `x <- action` if `action` has type `C something`, so because `getArgs` has type `IO [String]`, you can't directly call it from `main`, you first have to wrap the `IO` action into your `C` monad, here, with `lift` or `liftIO`

Answer (score 4):

If you desugar the `do` notation:

```
main = getArgs >>= (\ args -> case args of [] -> putStrLn "Argh!")
```

`getArgs` has type `IO [String]`. `>>=` pipes the resulting `[String]` into the lambda, which returns `IO ()`, the result of `putStrLn "..."`. Here, `>>=` has the inferred type:

```
(>>=) :: IO [String] -> ([String] -> IO ()) -> IO ()
```

So the type of the whole expression is `IO ()`, matching the signature of `main`.